# Maven Surefire with JUnit 5 hiding stacktraces

Tags: java, maven, junit, maven-surefire-plugin, junit5

If I do this:

```sh
mvn -X \
     -Dtest=MojoIntegrationTest \
     -Dsurefire.trimStackTrace=false \
     -Dsurefire.useFile=false  \
     clean test
```

```java
@BeforeEach
public void setUp() {
    stuff();
}

@Test
public void testMyApp() {
    doApp();
}
```

and `stuff()` or `doApp()` blows up somehow, I don't get the full stacktrace, neither in the console nor in the files. Either JUnit5 or Maven is hiding them:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.me.config.plugin.MojoIntegrationTest
Created C:\dev\workspace\gem-config-maven-plugin\target\test-classes\test-project\target
Tests run: 3, Failures: 3, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 2.133 sec <<< FAILURE! - in com.me.config.plugin.MojoIntegrationTest
testFindCommonPropertiesFromDependency  Time elapsed: 1.6 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.me.config.plugin.MojoIntegrationTest.setUp(MojoIntegrationTest.java:168)

testRetrievalOfConfigJar  Time elapsed: 0.283 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.me.config.plugin.MojoIntegrationTest.setUp(MojoIntegrationTest.java:168)

testOutputPropertiesFilesForAllEnvironments  Time elapsed: 0.2 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.me.config.plugin.MojoIntegrationTest.setUp(MojoIntegrationTest.java:168)


Results :

Failed tests: 
  MojoIntegrationTest.setUp:168 » NullPointer
  MojoIntegrationTest.setUp:168 » NullPointer
  MojoIntegrationTest.setUp:168 » NullPointer

Tests run: 3, Failures: 3, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 13.717 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-08-21T18:23:05+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 31M/389M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) on project gem-config-maven-plugin: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to C:\dev\workspace\gem-config-maven-plugin\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) on project gem-config-maven-plugin: There are test failures.

Please refer to C:\dev\workspace\gem-config-maven-plugin\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: There are test failures.
```

Apart from doing this:

```
@BeforeEach
public void setUp() {
    try {
        stuff();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }
 }
```

which I really don't like, how can I get the stacktrace?

Thanks.

**[UPDATE 1]**: the config for surefire from my pom:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                    <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
                </includes>
                <properties>
                    <excludeTags>integration</excludeTags>
                </properties>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider
                    </artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0-M5</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                    <version>5.0.0-M5</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

and the JUnit5 dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0-M5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
        <version>4.12.0-M5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

[Maven surefire docs here](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html)

**[UPDATE 2]**: originally this was just affecting my `@BeforeEach` routine, but now that I am writing tests, I realise it is actually everywhere, i.e. mvn and junit5 is hiding all my stacktraces.

Comment: Could you share the JUnit5 configuration in the pom.xml. Also if you've configured surefire as well please.

Comment: `catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        throw e;
    }` - you can get the error message from `e.getMessage()`.

Comment: What happens when you omit the `surefire.trimStackTrace` and `surefire.useFile` options?

Comment: Doesn't the same happen for JUnit 4 tests without using any custom provider?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have to use `-DtrimStackTrace=false` instead of `-Dsurefire.trimStackTrace=false`:

```
mvn clean test -DtrimStackTrace=false
```

See http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html for details.

Comment: What was really bizarre is that I could not find a command line example anywhere. The same problem for -DuseFile=false

Comment: All "user properties" in the documentation can be used with `-D`.